# Compile a LaTeX file from Vim and not from terminal

Tags: vim, latex

I am compiling my LaTeX files from terminal and it gets a little annoying to go every time in terminal and use:

```
xelatex "file-path"
```

Is there a way to do this from inside Vim?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
command C !xelatex %
```

in your `~/.vimrc`.

Then you can do:

```
:C
```

in vim to compile the file.

You can do more complex operations using functions:

```
function WriteCompileTex()
  write
  :! xelatex %
endfunction
command WC :call WriteCompileTex()
```

Note that user-defined commands and functions must begin with a capital letter.

You can also do:

```
au BufWritePost *.tex ! xelatex %
```

This will run this command whenever a `.tex` file is written to, so that you can simply do `:w`, and your Tex file will be compiled after saving.

Comment: Can you compose a command that first saves the file and then compiles the file? Something like `:wC`.

Comment: @martijnn2008 check the update.

Comment: The update didn't worked for me. Vim is starting with all kinds of messages/errors. What did work for me is `command WC write | !pdflatex %`.

Comment: @martijnn2008 case of the missing parentheses. I forgot to add them. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are serious about the couple `vim` + `latex`, my preferred option is to use the couple `latexxmk` + LaTeXBox.

[`latexmk`](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) is independent of the editor, really --- it's a script that watches the files needed to compile a latex document and re-run the compilation when needed. Configuration is a bit complex, but it is a really useful tool. For example, my setup for `xelatex` is having a `latexmkrc` file (in the same directory) like this:

```
$pdf_previewer = "start evince";
$pdf_pdf_update_method = 0;
$dvi_mode = 0;
$pdf_mode = 1;
$preview_continuous_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = "xelatex %O %S";
```

now you can run `latexmk file-name` (from the same directory!) and you will have automatic, background compilation every time you modify the file (or any dependent file --- like a drawing or a bibliography). Just save the file and watch the preview automatically update.

`latexmk` is in the [*universe* repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/148645/16395), so if you have that enabled you can simply install it by `sudo apt-get install latexmk`.

[LaTeX-BoX](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box) is a plugin for `vim` that simplify the editing of the LaTeX files, and uses `latexmk` to compile. Install it following the instruction on the linked page, and add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
" add a <comment> vim: set spelllang=es: to change language
" LaTeX:
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
autocmd FileType tex set spell wrap linebreak
let g:LatexBox_latexmk_async=1
let g:LatexBox_latexmk_preview_continuously=1
let g:LatexBox_quickfix=2
let g:LaTeXBox_output_type='' "Let latexmkrc choose the type
```

(change to your taste). Now you start the background compilation from `vim` with the command `\ll`.